# check the data in one activity and show the data another activity in android using php files

Tags: php, android

first how to match the consignment_no in php file
 and fetch the data in another activity to show all the data in second activity

**1) First Activity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    final Button GetServerData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    GetServerData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String serverURL = "http://eaglenew.comoj.com/courier_v1.php";

            Intent intObj = new Intent(IntentExampleActivity.this,GreetingActivity.class);
            intObj.putExtra("ConsNumber", data.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intObj);


        }
    });
}
```

**2) Second Activity**

```
public class GreetingActivity extends Activity {

    TextView greetMsg,jsonParsed;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.greeting);
        TextView  greetMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Intent intename = getIntent();
        String consignment_no = (String) intename.getSerializableExtra("ConsNumber");
        greetMsg.setText("Forwarded Air Way Bill No. " + consignment_no);
}
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? it's not clear what you are asking

Comment: if i am write the  one id in input text and this id checking out in Mysql Database if the id is existing the show the all data in next activity (show all data from database using php files)

Comment: there is alot of examples and questions for this, you just need to know what to search for, you need to know about `android send http request` and `php encode json from mysql database` have a look, read some examples you will do it

Comment: i am work in this but the value goes into the second activity but where i run the  json in second activity.... if you send me the some Question and example of the link.. Thanx in advance Yazan sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your question is wide and can't be shorted to a simple answer, it's actually a mini project, need multiple skills and knowledge. and that's what you have to learn

here is what you need to do (in steps):

1- get the ID from the text field in your android app

2- send a HTTP request (GET or POST) to a php page or webservice sending the ID as parameter to that page

3- in that php page, get the ID param value, use it in a db-query to get info

4- serialize (encode) the result to JSON format, and send it back `echo`

5- at mobile app, when you get the response from the php page, you have to parse it
and use the info in your app.

i will mention some links that helps you with the major steps:

1- [Mysql -> JSON](http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/JSON-example.php) check section title **MySQL and JSON**

2- [Android, Http request, Json parse](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

this should give you a clue on how to do this,.
you may not do the exact thing in the links, just get a hints on what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

use the following  code

```
intename.getExtra("ConsNumber");
```

instead of

```
intename.getSerializableExtra("ConsNumber");
```

Comment: I want to this sir...... if i am write the one id in input text and this id checking out in Mysql Database if the id is existing the show the all data in next activity (show all data from database using php files) –